# Command Not Found When Executed via PHP shell_exec()

Tags: linux, shell, php

I want to execute following command on my Ubuntu server using php:

```
android create project --target 8 --name $fname --path ./$fname --activity MainActivity --package $fpack 2>&1
```

The above command is to create an Android app project. So when I enter this command on my terminal then it works fine, but when I execute it via PHP:

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$fpack = $_POST['fpack'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Creating a new Android project.
var_dump(shell_exec("android create project --target 8 --name $fname --path ./$fname --activity MainActivity --package $fpack 2>&1"));

?>
```

When I run my PHP script I get the following output:

```
string(26) "sh: 1: android: not found "
```

Why it works when I enter manually in terminal (from user 'ashish' account) but not with php?  my apache user and group is same (ashish). Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What if you give the full path to android executable?

Comment: @Dan it works with full path but i need to type too much for that. any way to make it work with just 'android''? just typing android works in terminal

Comment: i thibnk I got a way, let me try using php `putenv` to set environment variables and report back

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but for those who experience this problem can try to set the environment variables of direct on the server. PHP uses the putenv () function.

Example:// Set Variable Enviromental

> ```
> $JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"; 
> $ANDROID_HOME = "/opt/android-sdk-linux";
> $PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/24.0.0-preview";
>
> putenv ("JAVA_HOME = $JAVA_HOME"); 
> putenv ("PATH = $PATH");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your $PATH is set incorrectly. Specify the full path to `android`, or set your path via something like this:

```
<?php
putenv(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array('/dir/containing/android', getenv('PATH')))
);

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$fpack = $_POST['fpack'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Create a new Android project
var_dump(shell_exec("android create project --target 8 --name $fname --path ./$fname --activity MainActivity --package $fpack 2>&1"));
```